# Editing value of an Object and duplicating it

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, nsobject

I have an events object which is given below

```
NSString *name;
NSString *date;
NSInteger id;
```

I am storing the events object in a NSMutabelArray. I want to add to the date and store in a different array. For that I am using the code below

```
NSString *curDate = event.Date;
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:curDate];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  Events *newEvent = event;
  NSDate *newDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*1];
  newEvent.date = [dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate];
  [deleg.events addObject:newEvent];
  date = newDate;
}
```

So after final iteration of loop all the objects in deleg.events is having the last calculated date. How can I resolve it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not making a new event. Your line

```
Events *newEvent = event;
```

is just creating a new variable that references the exact same event object, which means you now have added the exact same object to the array 5 times.

I don't know how your `Events` class works. If it conforms to NSCopying, then you can use

```
Events *newEvent = [[event copy] autorelease];
```

If not, you'll have to create a brand new `Events` object (using `[[Events alloc] init]` or whatever is appropriate for the class) and populate it with the appropriate data.